# Why does GregorianCalendar set method give slightly and inconsistent wrong times?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

In NetBeans, I run the code below.

The output from one run is

> ```
> Intended time   = 1970-0-1 0:0:0.000
> GC time in ms   = 102
> Reformated GC time = 1970-01-01 00:00:00.102
> Deprecated Date ms = 0
> Deprecated time    = 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
> ```

The output from another run is

> ```
> Intended time   = 1970-0-1 0:0:0.000
> GC time in ms   = 575
> Reformated GC time = 1970-01-01 00:00:00.575
> Deprecated Date ms = 0
> Deprecated time    = 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
> ```

Q1: Why is the Reformatted time (from GregorianCalendar set(...) method) have extra milliseconds - Deprecated  - using new Date(...) does not!

Q2: Why does the number of ms vary from run to run?

```
    public class TestGregorianCalendar {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String timeZoneString = "GMT+00";
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneString));
        int year = 1970;
        int month = 0;  // Jan
        int day = 1;
        int hour  = 0;
        int min  = 0;
        int sec  = 0;
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
        long ms;
        Date date;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneString));
        System.out.println("Intended time   = "+year+"-"+month+"-"+day
            +" "+hour+":"+min+":"+sec+".000");
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
        ms = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("GC time in ms   = "+Long.toString(ms));
        date = new Date(ms);
        System.out.println("Reformated GC time = "+df.format(date));
        Date deprecatedDate = new Date(year-1900, month, day, hour+1, min, sec);
        System.out.println("Deprecated Date ms = "+Long.toString(deprecatedDate.getTime()));
        System.out.println("Deprecated time    = "+df.format(deprecatedDate));  
    }
}
```

Grateful for insight!

Comment: Read [public GregorianCalendar()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#%3Cinit%3E()), it is initialized with the current time, so that includes milliseconds, but you aren't overwriting milliseconds in your code.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `GregorianCalendar`, `TimeZone`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `Instant`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
    
    long ms = dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(ms);
```

Output:

> ```
> 1970-01-01T00:00Z
> 0
> ```

There are no extra milliseconds, or they would gave been printed twice, once in each of the output lines. java.time sanely numbers months the same way humans do, so I have given January as 1. The last 0 in the argument list to `OffsetDateTIme.of()` is nanosecond of second and ensures that the fraction of second will be 0.

If you want formatted output:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));
```

> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000

### What went wrong in your code?

Mark Rotteveel already in the comment has answered both of your questions. `new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneString))` created a `GregorianCalendar` representing the current moment in the specified time zone, with millisecond precision. `calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)` sets the mentioned fields to those values. It does not change other fields such as era and millisecond (of second). So the millisecond value that you get reflects the time of the second the `GregorianCalendar` object was created, which obviously is not the same each time. This explains the apparently random variations. This is just one of very many confusing sides of `GregorianCalendar`. I recommend that you don’t use that class.

`new Date(year-1900, month, day, hour+1, min, sec)` — whoa, using the constructor that has been deprecated since February 1997 because it works unreliably across time zones — creates a new `Date` object from those values alone without looking at the clock, so here the millisecond of second is 0.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

### [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH)

`Instant.EPOCH` is the constant for the `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` epoch instant.

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH;
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

In case you need a date-time string representing the instant into a different pattern, you can convert it into `OffsetDateTime` using [`Instant#atOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atOffset-java.time.ZoneOffset-) and then format the same using a `DateTimeFormatter` instantiated with the desired pattern.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH;
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String formatted = formatter.format(instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.